# Importing multiple stacked raster images in R?

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, landsat

I would like to import all **multiple mosaic rasters** (each mosaic is composed by 7 layers) from indicated folder into my R. Then access them as single multilayers rasters.

[image]

So I did:

```
# read all mosaics named "mos....img" in R    
raster_data<-list.files(path=getwd(), pattern="mos.*.img$") 
# read files as rasters
s <- stack(raster_data)
# check my imported rasters p.ex. raster n°8 from "s" raster stack
s[[8]]
```

and my raster s[[8]] contain only 1 layer, so not the whole mosaic was imported!

```
nlayers(s[[8]])
[[1]]
```

If I read each mosaic separately, it works:

```
# read 1 mosaic (composed by 7 bands)
mosaic1<-brick("mosaic1.img")
# extract one band
band4<-subset(mosaic1, 4)
```

Why "stack" tool doesn´t import whole mosaics but only one band of the mosaic and how it is possible to arrange it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at `nlayers(s)`. The returned number of layers will equal 28 - at least for the above example with 4 multi-layer objects encompassing 7 layers each. Applying `stack` to multiple multi-layer files results in one huge 'RasterStack' object, i.e. all the single multi-layer objects are appended to one another.

If you would like to have separate stacks for each file, I would recommend using

```
s <- lapply(raster_data, stack)
```

which results in a list of 'RasterStack' objects, each including 7 layers rather than one huge stack. You may then access particular layers, e.g. the 2nd layer of the 3rd 'RasterStack' object, by

```
s[[3]][[2]]
```