# How import many raster in r?

Tags: raster, r, mosaic, extract, pixel

I have different raster layers, but it is not a mosaic. I want to extract all pixel values, mean and standard deviation for each raster. But I prepared my scrip in r, and I import each raster and extract information one by one raster information. When I want to read in other efficient for, for example use *stack*, but show this problem

```
> raster <- stack('C:/Users/Dinosca/Documents/Proyectos GRASS/Camp_500')
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) : 
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

Sorry, I have never worked with r and raster information before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Create a loop to iterate through files:

```r
library(raster)

raster_files <- list.files(mypath,full.names = T) #use pattern = '.tif$' or something else if you have multiple files in this folder

r_name <- list.files(mypath,full.names = F)

rList <- list() # to save raster values
statList <- list() # to save data.frame with statistics

for(i in 1:length(raster_files)){
  temp <- raster(raster_files[i])
  rList[[i]] <- values(temp) # extract values for each raster

  # name
  Name <- r_name[i]

  mx=raster::maxValue(temp)
  mn=raster::minValue(temp)
  avg=raster::cellStats(temp,'mean',na.rm=T)
  stdev=raster::cellStats(temp,'sd',na.rm=T)

  statList[[i]] <- data.frame(Name,mx,mn,avg,stdev) # create a data.frame to save statistics
}

df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,statList) # final data.frame with all statistics
```

---

#### Solution 2

You can use `purrr` package to handle this easily:

```r
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mypath <- 'C:/Users/Dinosca/Documents/Proyectos GRASS/Camp_500'

# To extract all pixel values (the result is a list, each slot is a raster)
list.files(mypath,full.names = T) %>% #use pattern = '.tif$' or something else if you have multiple files in this folder
  map(raster) %>% map(raster::values)

# To extract max, min, mean and sd for each raster (the result is a data.frame)
list.files(mypath,full.names = T) %>%
  map(raster) %>%
  map_df(function(x){
    data.frame(
      mx=raster::maxValue(x),
      mn=raster::minValue(x),
      avg=mean(x[],na.rm=T),
      stdev=sd(x[],na.rm=T))})
```

Comment: Using mean(x[]) negates the memory safe aspects of the raster package. While I appreciate new methods and tricky approaches, your answer obscures the basics. It would be nice to provide a clear, simple answer and then provide a plausibly faster and more efficient solution. Simply looping or using lapply on the vector of raster pointers, resulting from list.files, and then using raster::cellStats, which is memory safe, to collect statistics would be a clear approach, which is also a duplicate answer. Using purrr to replace a for loop is clever but, may really confuse a novice user.

Comment: I can understand his example, but i have the problem. When I want to create a raster list. R show this error: Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans you're right. I edited my answer adding a `for()` loop and replacing `x[]` with `cellStats()`.

Comment: @Dinosca did you check if in your folder are only one kind of file extension? If you have some `name.tif.aux.xml` or files like this will be an error

Comment: Yes, i had a problem with format. Thanks @aldo_tapia you are so friendly. But now I have another problem. But, i hope I can fix it.

Comment: @aldo_tapia and If I want to save a raster name in data frame, because I have 150 rasters. And finally, only save a average and sd values. But I used _getValues_ for each raster, I have many command lines

Comment: @Dinosca ready. Check the updated answer

Comment: @aldo_tapia I have a question, when I want to extract all values for different raster, I used **vl=raster::getValues(temp)**, but in the data frame there are many Na's and only a few cell has a number, and it is so rare because, if I extract only raster, this raster has values.

Comment: Try with `vl = temp[]`. Maybe you have a lot of NA and you don't know. To verify each raster with several plots add to loop `print(plot(is.na(temp)))`, 1 is a NA pixel and 0 is  valid value pixel

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into [`n-layers`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/nlayers)

`s <- lapply(raster_data, stack)`

This thread provided the above code [Importing multiple stacked raster images in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130360/importing-multiple-stacked-raster-images-in-r)

> Get the number of layers in a Raster* object, typically used with a (multilayer) RasterStack or RasterBrick object

This is a good tutorial [Image Raster Data in R - An Intro](http://neondataskills.org/R/Image-Raster-Data-In-R/) too look into as well.

Comment: I wrote my new code, and I am using the tutorial, but I can not read the stack function in Raster. Always show me: Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

Comment: late to the party, but you probably need to use the `full.names = T` argument in list.files. Or make sure your working directory is what you think it is. This means that it's having trouble finding the tif files.